# How to parse an xml to java class with recycler view or in adapter of recyclerview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, xml-parsing

I have an xml file which name it is Bookmark and it is into the xml folder.
I want to parse xml to recycler view which I can show the list of the Bookmark in recycler view.
The bookmark xml it is not in assets it is in res then xml folder.
This is my code.

Bookmark.xml in the xml folder

```
<Bookmarks>
    <Bookmark id="1" icon="google.png" name="Google" searchUrl="https://www.google.com" hidden="true" />
    <Bookmark id="2" icon="youtube_new.png" name="Youtube" searchUrl="http://m.youtube.com" />
    <Bookmark id="3" icon="facebook.png" name="Facebook" nativeUrl="facebook://" searchUrl="https://m.facebook.com" />
    <Bookmark id="4" icon="twitter.png" name="Twitter" searchUrl="https://mobile.twitte.com" />
    <Bookmark id="5" icon="instagram.png" name="Instagram" nativeUrl="instagram://" searchUrl="https:instagram.com" />
    <Bookmark id="6" icon="gmail.png" name="Gmail" nativeUrl="googlemail://" searchUrl="https://gmail.com" />
    <Bookmark id="7" icon="google_translate.png" name="Translate" searchUrl="https://" />

</Bookmarks>
```

This is the java class for recycler view

```
 public class FragmentBookmark extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;
    RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;

    public void onCreateView(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myRecyclerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1);
        myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        try {
            pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();

            InputStream in_s = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("bookmarks.xml");
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            parser.setInput(in_s, null);

            parseXML(parser);

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("OUTPUT", arrayList.get(i).toString());
        }

        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }

    private void parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        ArrayList<Bookmark> countries = null;
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        Bookmark country = null;

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String name;
            name = parser.getName();
            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    countries = new ArrayList();
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (name.equals("Bookmark")) {

                        Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
                        bookmark.setName(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
                        bookmark.setIcon(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "icon"));
                        bookmark.setId(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "id"));
                        bookmark.setSearchUrl(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "searchUrl"));
                        bookmark.setNativeUrl(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "nativeUrl"));
                        arrayList.add(bookmark);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }


    }

    private void processParsing(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        Bookmark bookmark = null;


    }
    }
```

This is the recycler view xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/listRecyclerView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:fillViewport="false">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

This is the adapter for recyclerview

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new ListViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        ((ListViewHolder) viewHolder).bindView(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return OurData.title.length;
    }

    private class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView mItemText;
        private ImageView mItemImage;

        public ListViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mItemText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            mItemImage =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void bindView(int position) {
            mItemText.setText(OurData.title[position]);
            mItemImage.setImageResource(OurData.picture[position]);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }
}
```

This is a java class which I have added manually and works in the recycler view but I need the Bookmark xml to show in recycler view

```
public class OurData {
    public static String[] title = new String[] {
            "Bing",
            "Facebook",
            "Gmail",
            "Translate",
            "Bing",
            "Facebook",
            "Gmail",
            "Translate"
    };

    public static int[] picture = new int[] {
            R.drawable.instagram,
            R.drawable.instagram,
            R.drawable.instagram,
            R.drawable.instagram,
            R.drawable.instagram,
            R.drawable.instagram,
            R.drawable.instagram,
            R.drawable.instagram

    };
}
```

This is the xml to show an Image and a TextView for recycler view

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.129"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.069"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_view" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **UPDATE 2**

> FragmentBookmark

```
public class FragmentBookmark extends Fragment {


    public FragmentBookmark() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;

    RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
    DataAdapter dataAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bookmark, container, false);

        myRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
        myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(mContext, arrayList);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        try {

            XmlPullParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.bookmarks);

            while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (xpp.getName().equals("Bookmark")) {

                        Log.e("MY_VALUE", " * " + xpp.getAttributeValue(0) + " * ");
                        Log.e("MY_VALUE", " * " + xpp.getAttributeValue(1) + " * ");
                        Log.e("MY_VALUE", " * " + xpp.getAttributeValue(5) + " * ");
                        Log.e("MY_VALUE", " * " + xpp.getAttributeValue(2) + " * ");
                        Log.e("MY_VALUE", " * " + xpp.getAttributeValue(3) + " * ");
                        Log.e("MY_VALUE", " * " + xpp.getAttributeValue(4) + " * ");


                        Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
                        bookmark.setName(xpp.getAttributeValue(0));

                        int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(xpp.getAttributeValue(1), "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
                        bookmark.setIcon(drawableResourceId);

                        bookmark.setId(xpp.getAttributeValue(2));

                        bookmark.setSearchUrl(xpp.getAttributeValue(3));
                        bookmark.setNativeUrl(xpp.getAttributeValue(4));
                        arrayList.add(bookmark);

                    }
                }

                xpp.next();
            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

> layout.fragment_bookmark

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> DataAdapter

```
public class DataAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public DataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {

        View view=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.tvName.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());

        holder.tvIcon.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getIcon());

        holder.tvId.setText(arrayList.get(position).getId());
        holder.tvSearchUrl.setText(arrayList.get(position).getSearchUrl());
        holder.tvNativeUrl.setText(arrayList.get(position).getNativeUrl());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvName,tvId,tvSearchUrl,tvNativeUrl;

        ImageView tvIcon;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            tvIcon=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvIcon);
            tvId=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvId);
            tvSearchUrl=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSearchUrl);
            tvNativeUrl=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNativeUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

> layout.custom_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Name  : " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Icon  : " />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tvIcon"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Id  : " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="SearchUrl  : " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSearchUrl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="NativeUrl  : " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNativeUrl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

> Bookmark model class

```
public class Bookmark
{
    String name,id,nativeUrl,searchUrl;
    int icon;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(int icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getNativeUrl() {
        return nativeUrl;
    }

    public void setNativeUrl(String nativeUrl) {
        this.nativeUrl = nativeUrl;
    }

    public String getSearchUrl() {
        return searchUrl;
    }

    public void setSearchUrl(String searchUrl) {
        this.searchUrl = searchUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bookmark{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", icon='" + icon + '\'' +
                ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", nativeUrl='" + nativeUrl + '\'' +
                ", searchUrl='" + searchUrl + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

### **UPDATE**

**XML FILE**

```
<Bookmarks>
    <Bookmark
        name="Google"
        hidden="true"
        icon="google.png"
        id="1"
        nativeUrl=""
        searchUrl="https://www.google.com" />
    <Bookmark
        name="Youtube"
        hidden=""
        icon="youtube_new.png"
        id="2"
        nativeUrl=""
        searchUrl="http://m.youtube.com" />
    <Bookmark
        name="Facebook"
        hidden=""
        icon="facebook.png"
        id="3"
        nativeUrl="facebook://"
        searchUrl="https://m.facebook.com" />
    <Bookmark
        name="Twitter"
        hidden=""
        icon="twitter.png"
        id="4"
        nativeUrl=""
        searchUrl="https://mobile.twitte.com" />
    <Bookmark
        name="Instagram"
        hidden=""
        icon="instagram.png"
        id="5"
        nativeUrl="instagram://"
        searchUrl="https:instagram.com" />
    <Bookmark
        name="Gmail"
        hidden=""
        icon="gmail.png"
        id="6"
        nativeUrl="googlemail://"
        searchUrl="https://gmail.com" />
    <Bookmark
        name="Translate"
        hidden=""
        icon="google_translate.png"
        id="7"
        nativeUrl=""
        searchUrl="https://" />

</Bookmarks>
```

Here is the code to parse **XML** from `res/XML` folder

```
    try {

        XmlPullParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.bookmarks);

        while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if (xpp.getName().equals("Bookmark")) {

                    Log.e("MY_VALUE", " * " + xpp.getAttributeValue(0) + " * ");
                    Log.e("MY_VALUE", " * " + xpp.getAttributeValue(1) + " * ");
                    Log.e("MY_VALUE", " * " + xpp.getAttributeValue(5) + " * ");
                    Log.e("MY_VALUE", " * " + xpp.getAttributeValue(2) + " * ");
                    Log.e("MY_VALUE", " * " + xpp.getAttributeValue(3) + " * ");
                    Log.e("MY_VALUE", " * " + xpp.getAttributeValue(4) + " * ");

                    Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
                    bookmark.setName(xpp.getAttributeValue(0));
                    bookmark.setIcon(xpp.getAttributeValue(1));
                    bookmark.setId(xpp.getAttributeValue(2));
                    bookmark.setSearchUrl(xpp.getAttributeValue(3));
                    bookmark.setNativeUrl(xpp.getAttributeValue(4));
                    arrayList.add(bookmark);

                }
            }

            xpp.next();
        }
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

There are three types of android XML parser that we can use.

- **`SAX Parsers`**
- **`DOM Parsers`**
- **`XMLPullParser`**

You can use [**`XmlPullParserFactory`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory) to parse your `xml`

Try this here is the working code

> MainActivity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;

    RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
    DataAdapter dataAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        try {
            pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();

            InputStream in_s = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("bookmark.xml");
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            parser.setInput(in_s, null);

            parseXML(parser);

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("OUTPUT", arrayList.get(i).toString());
        }

        dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(this, arrayList);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    private void parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        ArrayList<Bookmark> countries = null;
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        Bookmark country = null;

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String name;
            name = parser.getName();
            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    countries = new ArrayList();
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (name.equals("Bookmark")) {
                        Log.e("VALUE", parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name") + "");
                        Log.e("VALUE", parser.getAttributeValue(null, "icon") + "");
                        Log.e("VALUE", parser.getAttributeValue(null, "id") + "");
                        Log.e("VALUE", parser.getAttributeValue(null, "searchUrl") + "");
                        Log.e("VALUE", parser.getAttributeValue(null, "nativeUrl") + "");

                        Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
                        bookmark.setName(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
                        bookmark.setIcon(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "icon"));
                        bookmark.setId(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "id"));
                        bookmark.setSearchUrl(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "searchUrl"));
                        bookmark.setNativeUrl(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "nativeUrl"));
                        arrayList.add(bookmark);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }


    }

    private void processParsing(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        Bookmark bookmark = null;


    }
}
```

> layout.activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> DataAdapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public DataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {

        View view=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.tvName.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
        holder.tvIcon.setText(arrayList.get(position).getIcon());
        holder.tvId.setText(arrayList.get(position).getId());
        holder.tvSearchUrl.setText(arrayList.get(position).getSearchUrl());
        holder.tvNativeUrl.setText(arrayList.get(position).getNativeUrl());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvName,tvIcon,tvId,tvSearchUrl,tvNativeUrl;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            tvIcon=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvIcon);
            tvId=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvId);
            tvSearchUrl=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSearchUrl);
            tvNativeUrl=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNativeUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

> layout.custom_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Name  : " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Icon  : " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Id  : " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="SearchUrl  : " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSearchUrl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="NativeUrl  : " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNativeUrl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

> Bookmark model class

```
public class Bookmark
{
    String name,icon,id,nativeUrl,searchUrl;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNativeUrl() {
        return nativeUrl;
    }

    public void setNativeUrl(String nativeUrl) {
        this.nativeUrl = nativeUrl;
    }

    public String getSearchUrl() {
        return searchUrl;
    }

    public void setSearchUrl(String searchUrl) {
        this.searchUrl = searchUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bookmark{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", icon='" + icon + '\'' +
                ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", nativeUrl='" + nativeUrl + '\'' +
                ", searchUrl='" + searchUrl + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

for more information please check below post

- [Android - XML Parser](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm)
- [Android XML Parser – XMLPullParser](https://www.journaldev.com/10653/android-xml-parser-xmlpullparser)
- [How to read XML File in Java (DOM Parser)](https://www.journaldev.com/898/read-xml-file-java-dom-parser)
- [Java SAX Parser Example](https://www.journaldev.com/1198/java-sax-parser-example)
- [Parsing XML data in Android Apps](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/parsing-xml-data-in-android-apps-71ef607fbb16)
- [Android XML Parsing using DOM Parser](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-xml-parsing-using-dom-parser)
- [Android XML Parsing Tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/)
- [Learning to Parse XML Data in Your Android App](https://www.sitepoint.com/learning-to-parse-xml-data-in-your-android-app/)

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Do you know icon are images from the drawable-hdpi and to show the icons not strings.

Comment: @Spritzig where your icon is stored means in  `drawable` folder

Comment: Yes they are there stored

Comment: @Spritzig but Where

Comment: in the folder ~ drawable hdpi ~

Comment: And do you know in the Fragment to write the code not in the Main Activity ?
Because I need in the Fragment not in the Main Activity

Comment: I have changed the fragment like this but I don't see nothing in the Fragment Bookmark.
See the changed code for java Fragment Bookmark.

Comment: I have copied your project in a new project and it is not working?

Comment: And the bookmark.xml is not in the assets it is in the resource xml folder.
and you code it is not working ?

Comment: @Spritzig you  need to add your `bookmark.xml` folder

Comment: But do you know in Fragment not in Main Activity to write the code and if you can edit the code so I can understand better because for the moment I am confused, you have added a code now for try and catch but where should I implement that.
Please if you can edit all the code so it might be more understandable and please for Fragment not for MainActivity

Comment: Thank you hope this will work and if you can in the fragment to show only the icon and the name down the icon

Comment: @Spritzig check updated answer let me know if any help required

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184792/discussion-between-spritzig-and-nilesh-rathod).

Comment: The icons are not shown, they are png images makes that problem ?

Comment: @Spritzig  `The icons are not shown` did u get any error sorry for late reply

Comment: can you check my question or can we talk in a room because I have some question about android.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54233815/how-to-use-bitmap-to-show-a-favicon-of-an-web-for-a-viewholder

Comment: @Spritzig yes sure

Comment: @Spritzig can u share your url in which from you want to get icon

Comment: This I don't know because it depends from the user which uses but the url it is saved in searchUrl which is declared as String, so everytime it is different

Comment: @Spritzig i have added a solution in your question please check it

Comment: I will try to reproduce the code because I need to paste to the viewHolder.tvIcon or If you can give me an orientation where I need to put this code.

Comment: @Spritzig in which you want to set icon menas in your `viewHolder.tvIcon`

Comment: Yes in viewHolder.tvIcon, the Url comes from SearchUrl which is a void and set there the url on the saved Bookmark.

Comment: @Spritzig i have updated my answer please check it there is any help reqired than please letmeno in your otehr question also please added comment in that answer (means here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54266654/7666442)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/novoda/simple-easy-xml-parser) library to parse **XML** into your **POJO** file. parsing can be done in your **Fragment**.