# How to read all tag and values from xml java android?

Tags: java, xml

I have been searching for reading XML tags and its values, what I can find is reading the values using the tag names, but without knowing the tag names, is it possible to read all values?

```
<mytable diffgr:id="mytable1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
 <id>1203</id>                                              
 <no>25624</no>                
 <tarih>05/11/2018</tarih>                   
</mytable>
<mytable diffgr:id="mytable2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
 <id>39</id>                 
 <no>25624</no>               
 <tarih>07/09/2018</tarih>                    
</mytable>
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53593870/7666442

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml